# PhoneGap Reference Not found Error

Tags: android, cordova, compiler-errors, cordova-2.0.0

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/libs/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="checkConnection();">Just</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get Internet Connection type on android mobile
This is code which I have referred from official PhoneGap page
It giving me error **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Connection at file**

Please help me to get out of it...

Comment: You are using phonegap build to build your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap Build to build your application thet you have to include Phongap.js tag in head section. Like-

```
 <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

You just have to include this tag rest Phoneap will take care of that.

Refer [**Phonegap Doc**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) for network state.